# Informal meet after the application of a tenure-track position

Tags: tenure-track, interview

I applied for a tenure-track position a few months ago, and I just received an email from one of the members of the search committee. They mentioned the possibility of having an informal meeting during an upcoming conference (a kind of meet-and-greet). However, if it is not convenient for me, they are open to arranging another informal meeting time or location.

May I ask that is there any benefits to attending such an informal meet? Thank you.

P.S. It seems like this email was not sent only to me (as the recipients were hidden, and I can only see the sender and three other members of the search committee).

Comment: Well, you have applied and they want to chat with you, presumably to see how good of a fit you might be to then decide to proceed to an official interview. You can either have the meeting, and both sides get relevant information on the application, or you can skip the meeting and not give them more info to make a decision to invite to an interview. Your call.

Comment: hi @Jon Custer, thank you. The situation is that I am currently in another country, so basically, I cannot attend the conference. Do you think there's any difference if I request a Zoom meeting before (or after) the conference, or a face-to-face meeting after the conference? (I will be back in the USA a few days after that conference.)

Comment: @rorocc - please put in the information that you won't be at the conference

Comment: This doesn't qualify as an answer, but mainly a comment about the appropriateness of such an "informal" meeting. Do you know if this is part of their official vetting process? If not, then I would feel uncomfortable about what role (if any) this meeting should play in the decision to interview you. Does anyone else get this vibe from having (what could be) a pre-interview that is unsanctioned by the hiring institution?

Comment: @user138719 - depends a lot on actual policy. Telephone pre-screening interviews are certainly sanctioned by my (non-univerisity) HR department in order to better determine fit between the candidate and the posting beyond what is in the standard application submittal material.

Comment: @JonCuster "depends a lot on actual policy" -- Exactly. In all of the hiring work I've done, the importance of maintaining equal (and documented!) treatment of candidates has been made clear by university HR departments. Anything done "off script" is usually forbidden to avoid the appearance of rating candidates based on things other than those advertised in the minimum and preferred qualifications. I just wondered if what is being described as "informal" is actually part of the official process, as I'm sure they'd keep notes and forward them to HR, etc. If so, "informal" may be misleading.

Comment: hi @user138719, the email said, "We can have a brief conversation to align your faces with your resumes and meanwhile you can learn more about our university" On a deeper level, I felt that it carries the meaning of checking if our auras resonate well with each other. however, they also indicated if you have no time you don't need to make a special trip, you can contact one of them (cc in the email) to arrange another meet time and location. I'm not sure if it's a 'culture' thing in the USA?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect they are trying to save some money by meeting applicants where they don't need to pay for a visit. There isn't anything wrong with that, but it may be less "informal" than you think.

It would be to your advantage to meet with them, and consider the meeting an important one. If you don't and they meet someone "interesting" there, then you will find yourself at a disadvantage.

It also gives you a chance to evaluate them, which can be good. Finding mutual interest(s) can be an advantage.

Comment: hi buffy thank you.  I am currently in another country, which means I cannot attend the conference in person. I was wondering if there's any difference between requesting a Zoom meeting before or after the conference, or alternatively, a face-to-face meeting after the conference? (Just to clarify, I will be back in the USA a few days after the conference)

Comment: A zoom meet sounds like a good plan. Explain your circumstances if you request it.